# Rails 4 form: checkbox not saving value to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, checkbox, persistence

I have a Rails 4 app with the following `Post` model:

```
create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "calendar_id"
    t.date     "date"
    t.time     "time"
    t.string   "subject"
    t.string   "format"
    t.text     "copy"
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
    t.string   "short_copy"
    t.integer  "score"
    t.boolean  "facebook"
    t.boolean  "twitter"
    t.boolean  "instagram"
    t.boolean  "pinterest"
    t.boolean  "google"
    t.boolean  "linkedin"
    t.boolean  "tumblr"
    t.boolean  "snapchat"
    t.string   "approval"
  end
```

Users must be allowed to decide whether `post.facebook` is `true` or `false`, which is the reason why `:facebook` is a `boolean`.

Then, I created the following form to allow users to actually make `post.facebook` `true` or `false`:

```
<%= form_for [@calendar, @calendar.posts.build], html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <hr>

  <div class="field">
    <h3>Post details</h3>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :date %>
      <%= f.date_select :date %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :time %>
      <%= f.time_select :time %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :format %>
      <%= f.select :format, ['Simple Status', 'Image', 'Link', 'Video'] %>
    </p>
    <hr>
    <h3>Post content</h3>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :subject %>
      <%= f.text_field :subject %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :copy %>
      <%= f.text_area :copy %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :short_copy, "Short copy (Twitter only)" %>
      <%= f.text_area :short_copy %>
    </p>
    <hr>
    <h3>Social channels</h3>
    <p>
      <%= f.label_tag(:facebook, "Facebook" )%>
      <%= f.check_box_tag(:facebook) %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.label_tag(:twitter, "Twitter") %>
      <%= f.check_box_tag(:twitter) %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.label_tag(:instagram, "Instagram") %>
      <%= f.check_box_tag(:instagram) %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.label_tag(:pinterest, "Pinterest") %>
      <%= f.check_box_tag(:pinterest) %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.label_tag(:google, "Google+") %>
      <%= f.check_box_tag(:google) %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.label_tag(:linkedin, "LinkedIn") %>
      <%= f.check_box_tag(:linkedin) %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.label_tag(:tumblr, "Tumblr") %>
      <%= check_box_tag(:tumblr) %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.label_tag(:snapchat, "Snapchat") %>
      <%= f.check_box_tag(:snapchat) %>
    </p>
    <hr>
    <h3>Image</h3>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :image %><br>
      <%= f.file_field :image %>
    </p>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And I did sanitize all parameters in my `posts_controller.rb`:

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:date, :time, :subject, :format, :copy, :image, :short_copy, :score, :facebook, :twitter, :instagram, :pinterest, :google, :linkedin, :tumblr, :snapchat, :approval)
end
```

The problem is, whenever I try to `create` a new post or `edit` an existing post, and check the `:facebook` checkbox, then save the post, the value is still set to `nil`.

—————

**UPDATE**: here are my server logs, when I try to update a post:

```
Started PATCH "/posts/2" for ::1 at 2015-10-16 11:13:38 -0700
Processing by PostsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"gqhmCHecVEJdqvOE18HQTEVk+jlcJ9pBi1hYJ+7GQuXHUW2VbDyZggDlCx9uKddI+iCXkd1yhrW9RWZXv4/oUw==", "post"=>{"date(1i)"=>"2015", "date(2i)"=>"9", "date(3i)"=>"22", "time(1i)"=>"2000", "time(2i)"=>"1", "time(3i)"=>"1", "time(4i)"=>"08", "time(5i)"=>"15", "format"=>"Image", "subject"=>"Yet another image test.", "copy"=>"What about it this time?", "short_copy"=>""}, "facebook"=>"1", "commit"=>"Update Post", "id"=>"2"}
  Post Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/calendars/3
Completed 302 Found in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

From there, I would say that `"facebook"=>"1"` and the post is saved, but when I go to the `rails console` in Terminal, I still get `"facebook"=>nil`.

—————

**UPDATE 2**: here are the new server logs, when I use `<%= check_box_tag(["post"]["facebook"]) %>`:

```
Started PATCH "/posts/2" for ::1 at 2015-10-16 11:24:07 -0700
Processing by PostsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ByX04ciySTvKglgJGdTGsXSIOou443o02FfPJqNSn6BC3P980xKE+5fNoJKgPMG1y8xXIzm2JsDuSvFW8hs1Fg==", "post"=>{"date(1i)"=>"2015", "date(2i)"=>"9", "date(3i)"=>"22", "time(1i)"=>"2000", "time(2i)"=>"1", "time(3i)"=>"1", "time(4i)"=>"08", "time(5i)"=>"15", "format"=>"Image", "subject"=>"Yet another image test.", "copy"=>"What about it this time?", "short_copy"=>""}, "facebook"=>"1", "commit"=>"Update Post", "id"=>"2"}
  Post Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/calendars/3
Completed 302 Found in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

—————

**UPDATE 3**: and here are (again) some new server logs when I use `<%= check_box_tag("post[facebook]") %>`:

```
Started PATCH "/posts/2" for ::1 at 2015-10-16 11:31:25 -0700
Processing by PostsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"vOBGP+yXhCd9GpIbOx6+UqZCptsQcBKvfX5MM2sgvHz5GU2i9zdJ5yBVaoCC9rlWGQbLc5ElTltLY3JDOmkWyg==", "post"=>{"date(1i)"=>"2015", "date(2i)"=>"9", "date(3i)"=>"22", "time(1i)"=>"2000", "time(2i)"=>"1", "time(3i)"=>"1", "time(4i)"=>"08", "time(5i)"=>"15", "format"=>"Image", "subject"=>"Yet another image test.", "copy"=>"What about it this time?", "short_copy"=>""}, "facebook"=>"1", "commit"=>"Update Post", "id"=>"2"}
  Post Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/calendars/3
Completed 302 Found in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

—————

**UPDATE 4**: and yet some more server logs, when I use `<%= f.checkbox :facebook %>`:

```
Started PATCH "/posts/2" for ::1 at 2015-10-16 11:35:32 -0700
Processing by PostsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"kl0vM/bXVM+0m9z4JD4g/HcVA5YY4NYOfGnd/YP7kjjXpCSu7XeZD+nUJGOd1if4yFFuPpm1ivpKdOON0rI4jg==", "post"=>{"date(1i)"=>"2015", "date(2i)"=>"9", "date(3i)"=>"22", "time(1i)"=>"2000", "time(2i)"=>"1", "time(3i)"=>"1", "time(4i)"=>"08", "time(5i)"=>"15", "format"=>"Image", "subject"=>"Yet another image test.", "copy"=>"What about it this time?", "short_copy"=>""}, "facebook"=>"1", "commit"=>"Update Post", "id"=>"2"}
  Post Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/calendars/3
Completed 302 Found in 9ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

—————

How can I get the following behavior:

- Default value of `post.facebook` => `false`
- Default state of the `:facebook` checkbox => `unchecked`
- Value of `post.facebook` when the `:facebook` checkbox is checked => `true`
- State of the `:facebook` checkbox when the `:facebook` checkbox is checked => `checked`

I found the following Stack Overflow questions but could not figure out a solution to my issue from there:

- [Ruby on Rails - Checkbox not saving to database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217726/ruby-on-rails-checkbox-not-saving-to-database)
- [Rails Checkbox not working - no error when submitting form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26588512/rails-checkbox-not-working-no-error-when-submitting-form)
- [Get checkbox to render as checked if boolean value is false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846180/get-checkbox-to-render-as-checked-if-boolean-value-is-false)

This seems like a basic requirement / problem, and I believe I followed the Rails documentation, but I can't figure it out.

Any idea of what I am missing / doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your facebook attribute is not inside the post parameter.

Changes you have to make:

```
<%= form_for [@calendar, @post], html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
```

and

```
<%= f.check_box :facebook, checked: true %>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo (in my code, not only in the question). I fixed it but still get the same issue.

Comment: I updated my answer. Are you sure that the post gets saved?

Comment: Thanks. I updated the question to answer your comment ;) I believe the post is saved, yes.

Comment: From your server logs I can see, that facebook is not inside the post parameter hash. It's outside. I updated my answer.

Comment: I had not seen that: what does it mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: I tried both of your solution but still get the same problem. Any other idea?

Comment: New server log please

Comment: Sure, please **UPDATE 2**.

Comment: I changed the code. Please try and show logs again.

Comment: Did you try `<%= f.checkbox :facebook %>`?

Comment: Done: new server logs in **UPDATE 3**. I am going to try `<%= f.checkbox :facebook %>` now.

Comment: Yes, I just did, please see **UPDATE 4**.

Comment: Stack Overflow recommends we switch to the chat: should we?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92533/discussion-between-crispychicken-and-thibaud-clement).

Comment: Did you fix it or not?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you should have the information you need from `@crispychicken`, however as you seem to be struggling with getting it working, here's what you need to do:

```
#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
   def new
       @calendar = Calendar.find params[:calendar_id]
       @post = @calendar.posts.new
   end

   def create
       @calendar = Calendar.find params[:calendar_id]
       @post = @calendar.posts.new post_params
       @post.save
   end

   private

   def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:date, :time, :subject, :format, :copy, :image, :short_copy, :score, :facebook, :twitter, :instagram, :pinterest, :google, :linkedin, :tumblr, :snapchat, :approval)
   end
end
```

This will allow you to use the following in your form:

```
#app/views/posts/new.html.erb
<%= form_for [@calendar, @post] do |f| %>
    <%= f.check_box :facebook %>
<% end %>
```

This, accompanied with your other code, should be able to create a new `post` with the `facebook` value inserted.

---

Some pointers on your code:

--

**Loops**

Always use loops or [partials](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) to cut out inefficient code.

Also, don't use HTML to stylize your app. You're using `<hr>` when you could easily use `border-top` on one of your divs. `<hr>` should *only* be used to genuinely provide a horizontal rule in your actual content, *not* as a stylization element.

```
#app/views/shared/_errors.html.erb
<%= content_tag :div, class: error_explanation do %>
   <%= content_tag :h2, "#{pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this post from being saved:" %>
   <%= content_tag :ul do %>
      <%= errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
         <%= content_tag :li, message %>
      <% end %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>

#app/views/posts/new.html.erb
<%= form_for [@calendar, @post], html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
  <% render "errors", locals: { errors: @post.errors } if @post.errors.any? %>

  <%= content_tag :div, class: "field" do %>
    <%= content_tag :h3, "Post details" %>

    <% time = %i(date time) %>
    <% time.each do |t| %>
       <%= content_tag :p do %>
            <%= f.label :t %>
            <%= f.send("#{t}_select", t %>
       <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <%= content_tag :p do %>
      <%= f.label :format %>
      <%= f.select :format, ['Simple Status', 'Image', 'Link', 'Video'] %>
    <% end %>

    <%= content_tag :h3, "Post content" %>
    <% opts = [[:subject, "text_field"],[:copy, "text_area"]] %>
    <% opts.each do |type, field| %>
       <%= content_tag :p do %>
           <%= f.label type %>
           <%= f.send(field, type) %>
       <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <%= content_tag :p do %>
      <%= f.label :short_copy, "Short copy (Twitter only)" %>
      <%= f.text_area :short_copy %>
    <% end%>


    <% content_tag :h3, "Social channels" %>
    <% social = %i(facebook twitter instagram pinterest google linkedin tumblr snapchat) %>
    <% social.each do |s| %>
       <%= content_tag :p do %>
          <%= f.label_tag(s, s.to_s.titleize)%>
          <%= f.check_box_tag s %>
       <% end %>
    <% end %>


    <%= content_tag :h3, "Post Image" %>
    <%= content_tag :p do %>
      <%= f.label :image %>
      <%= f.file_field :image %>
    <% end %>

  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your help is much appreciated.